# JQuery change generated css code using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running a script that creates a bunch of css code at runtime.

I can change the code with firebug so I was wandering on how I could change this example css code using jquery?

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 100% !important; border: 3px solid #333 !important;padding: 1px !important; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 11px !important;">
```

Comment: WOW you used more effort creating your question than you would have to use the jQuery help ..... poor poor question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('table').css({firstStyle:"value",secondStyle:'value'});
```